# worker process in production, queue_classic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process

I'm using a queue_classic gem in my rails application (https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic, http://railscasts.com/episodes/344-queue-classic)
What is the best way of running a worker process on my vps in production environment? Is a detached screen session a good idea?
Should i add cron entry to lunch it on restart in case of a restart? Maybe there is a simpler way of doing it?

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question, while a good one, doesn't quite fit the scope of SO (see the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It's probably more suitable for [the Programmers Stack Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). That said, letting a program designed to manage daemons and background processes is likely your best bet. God, Monit, and Upstart (if using Ubuntu) are all popular choices.

Comment: I think this is an excellent question for either. Which one of the 1000 different stacks can a guy go to ?  People on stack, these types of questions are so valuable to your ecosystem too, cause when you really need them, the lesser stacks have no real traffic and barely come up in google.