# How to monitor background jobs in production, queue_classic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backgroundworker, queue-classic

I am using [queue_classic](https://github.com/ryandotsmith/queue_classic) for background jobs,
I need to monitor background jobs in production ie start, stop etc.
I found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516942/worker-process-in-production-queue-classic) but it didn't help me
Also I found the god code:
but how would I stop, restart workers?

```
number_queues.times do |queue_num|
  God.watch do |w|
    w.name = "QC-#{queue_num}"
    w.group = "QC"
    w.interval = 5.minutes
    w.start = "bundle exec rake queue:work" # This is your rake task to start QC listening
    w.gid = 'nginx' 
    w.uid = 'nginx'
    w.dir = rails_root
    w.keepalive
    w.env = {"RAILS_ENV" => rails_env} 
    w.log = "#{log_dir}/qc.stdout.log"  # Or....    "#{log_dir}//qc-#{queue_num}.stdout.log"

    # determine the state on startup
    w.transition(:init, { true => :up, false => :start }) do |on|
      on.condition(:process_running) do |c|
        c.running = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
This code seems doesn't work

```
namespace :queue_classic do
  desc "Start QC worker"
  task :start, roles: :web do
    run "cd #{release_path} && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake qc:work"
  end
  after "deploy:restart", "queue_classic:restart"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [documentation](http://godrb.com/) you can restart your worker by issuing

```
god restart QC-<worker_number>
```

where `QC-<worker_number>` is the name you assign to your worker

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of monitoring you need, you might also look at [Toro](https://github.com/tombenner/toro), which provides a great deal of monitoring, both in a web interface and through the fact that jobs store a great deal of data and can easily be queried using ActiveRecord queries. Toro also supports middleware, which may be useful for your needs.